# onComplete() is not getting called with DisposableSubscriber

Tags: android, realm, rx-java2

i am fetching realm result using `findAllAync` with `rxjava` operators as below

```
 Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();


        realm.where(cls).equalTo("syncInfo.syncStatus",false)
                .findAllAsync()
                .asFlowable()
                .filter(ts->ts.isLoaded())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(
                        new DisposableSubscriber<RealmResults<T>>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onNext(RealmResults<T> realmResults) {

                                Log.i(TAG, "onNext");
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(Throwable t) {
                                    Log.i(TAG, "onError");
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onComplete() {
                                Log.i(TAG, "onComplete");

                            }
                        }
                );



        realm.close();
```

the problem is my `onComplete` is not getting called and only `onNext` is getting called. as i want to perform certain operation on `onComplete` hence it is required that it gets called.

Comment: Well of course. RealmChangeListener never "completes". Have you ever seen a View.OnClickListener complete? Doesn't make any sense, does it?

Comment: okay so it depends upon the source , sorry i am pretty new to streams and rx

Comment: OnComplete is called only if the source emits `onComplete`, which Realm won't, because it's a hot observable (and doesn't terminate).

Comment: then show should we dispose it , by capturing disposable returned by the subscriber ?

Comment: yeah. That's why you get the Disposable, use `subscribeWith`